# Sorting strings variables in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have four strings. These four represents 4 quarters.
these four strings are: (Which are actually in sorting order according to my computer) .
Which is theoretically true in the world of strings.
Q1FY15
Q2FY15
Q3FY14
Q4FY14.

But if I consider the year part as well, then after sorting in increasing order I want the result to be as

Q3FY14
Q4FY14
Q1FY15
Q2FY15

Can someone tell me whether this is possible without considering substring complications :)

Comment: Did one of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not without substrings.  You can make a reference column combining  =right(quartercell,2) & =left(quartercell,2), but those are substring functions, though they don't use the term substring

Answer (score 0):

If you can use code, you could use the following sub to sort your info how you would like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortStrings()
'This sub will sort the values in column 1 by year and then by quarter based on
'the format of "Q1FY14"
'
'Written by TheEngineer on 12/10/2014

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim qCount  As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = i + 1 To LastRow
            If CInt(Right(.Cells(j, 1).Value, 2)) > CInt(Right(.Cells(i, 1).Value, 2)) Then
                If j <> i + 1 Then
                    .Cells(j, 1).Cut
                    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(j, 1).Cut
                .Cells(i, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    qCount = 0
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = i + 1 To LastRow
            If CInt(Right(.Cells(j, 1).Value, 2)) = CInt(Right(.Cells(i, 1).Value, 2)) Then
                qCount = qCount + 1
            End If
        Next j

        For k = i + 1 To qCount + i
            If CInt(Left(Right(.Cells(k, 1).Value, Len(.Cells(k, 1).Value) - 1), 1)) > CInt(Left(Right(.Cells(i, 1).Value, Len(.Cells(i, 1).Value) - 1), 1)) Then
                If k <> i + 1 Then
                    .Cells(k, 1).Cut
                    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(k, 1).Cut
                .Cells(i, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next k
    qCount = 0
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that this sub assumes that your info is in column 1 and that only the info you want sorted is in that column.

This will work for as many strings as you need.